# How can I suppress the output to console when importing packages in RPy2 in Python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Whenever I run a script importing packages with `import` in RPy2 in Python, there are always some extra lines popping up in the console. I pasted in an example below. How can I suppress that behavior?

```
CookieJar:r cookies$ python script.py 

    ‘tseries’ version: 0.10-24

    ‘tseries’ is a package for time series analysis and computational
    finance.

    See ‘library(help="tseries")’ for details.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could temporarily redirect the output stream to a blackhole just before the spammy peice of code.

```
import sys

class Blackhole(object):

    def write(self, string):
        pass

stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Blackhole()

function_el_spammo()

sys.stdout = stdout
```

Answer (score 7):

Besides `require(tseries, quietly = TRUE)` and using `sink()`, or its Python equivalent, there is also the simple

```
suppressMessages( library( tseries ))
```

which I prefer.

Answer (score 2):

In your R script, I would preload the `tseries` package (just in case if its called by some other functio/package) using

```
require(tseries, quietly = TRUE)
```